# Glassfish 3.1.2 lib/jar referral from ejb.jar issue

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have been working on migrating our code base onto Glassfish 3.1.2 using Java 7. I have been struck with this issue, where the deployment of EAR fails. I have an EAR, having modules, ejb.jar, couple of war files, along with lib directory having jar files to be shared across other modules within the EAR.

The issue is that ejb.jar refers to some spring bean definitions in lib/abc.jar file and is unable to find the spring file. The structure is like this:

EAR

- ejb.jar (some spring files in here refer to lib spring file like, xyz.xml importing spring/abc.context.xml)
- couple of war projects.
- lib/lot of jar files (one of the jar here contains the spring file being referred from ejb.jar, note the file is inside directory inside the jar, like spring/abc-context.xml)

But the ejb jar cant load the bean  definitions from lib/.jar

I have tried using the Manifest.MF inside the ejb.jar to refer to lib/abc.jar, but with no luck....

Not sure if there is some sort of problem with new GF 3.1.2, why its not able to respect the Manifest file. Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the JVM doesnt like the manually edited Manifest file and my guess is that windows is adding something like a carriage return etc. I managed to get it working by using the ant to generate the manifest file instead.

Thanks and hope that helps someone.